# Unable to find main class after 'mvn clean install'

Tags: spring, maven, nuxt.js

Using Intellij IDA, I try to build both frontend (Nuxt.js) and backend (Springboot) by maven. But these are not the code I made, I have difficulty to build.

The project structure is composed as below.

```
Rest
|- resources
   |- vue [frontend]
      |- .nuxt
      |- ...
      ...
      nuxt.config.js
      pom.xml
|- src [backend]
   |- main
      |- java
         |- A.B.C
            ...
            Application.java
   pom.xml

pom.xml
```

In `pom.xml` in `Rest`,

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.22.RELEASE</version> 
        <relativePath/> 
</parent>

    <groupId>A.B</groupId>
    <artifactId>C</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>C</name>
    <description>C_api</description>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <main.basedir>${project.basedir}</main.basedir>
    </properties>

    <modules>
        <module>src</module>
        <module>resources/vue</module>
    </modules>
```

In `pom.xml` in `Rest/src`

```
<project ...
...
     <parent>
        <groupId>A.B</groupId>
        <artifactId>C</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    ...

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            ...
    </build>
</project>
```

When `mvn clean install` in `Rest`, I got some errors: `Execution default of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.22.RELEASE:repackage failed: Unable to find main class`.

So I tried to solve errors by deleting plugin `spring-boot-maven-plugin` from `pom.xml` of `Rest`, but It didn't work. How should I fix this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In maven there is a [Standard Directory Layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) according to which your "backend" module should look like this:

```
|<module-name>
   |- src [backend]
      |- main
         |- java
            |- A.B.C
               ...
               Application.java
   pom.xml
```

Change it to the aforementioned structure and your code should start working.